# Software to manage a sales team (CRM, sales funnel)

Tags: project-management, crm

I am looking for software that would be best for this use case. I have a company, I find customers online, my team contacts them and offers them our products. I want to note their basic details like name, contact, the product ordered, delivery due date and the seller's name that they are assigned to. Also, I have an online marketing team. I want to see who brought in which customer. I want to give them access to add customers to the list too. At the end of the month, I want to see how much commission each team member gets. It would be nice if the software allows me to analyze the data like sales, expenses etc.

Currently, I'm handling this using Microsoft Excel.

Comment: Should it be a webapp? Do you want your employees to be able to enter new information?

Comment: Thank you for replying. No. It can be anything. It's a plus if the software allows them to. If not, it won't cause any trouble. I just want an upgrade from Microsoft Excel.